# Redux/Reducer - dispatching doesnt change state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

As the title says, i dispatch an action but my state doesnt change. Here's some code:

**App.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './../reducer/reducer'
import { TEST } from './../reducer/actions'

// Initial store 
const initialStore = {
    name: "John",
    count: 0
};

const store = createStore(reducer, initialStore);
store.dispatch({ type: TEST })
console.log(store.name);
```

**Reducer.js**

```
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, TEST } from './actions'

function reducer (state, action)  {
    console.log(state, action);
    
    if(action.type === TEST){
        console.log("TEST");
        return {...state, name: "Mark"};
    }

    return state;
}

export default reducer;
```

**package.json**

```
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
```

- `console.log('TEST)` from `reducer.js` prints 'TEST' but `state name` stays the same.
- `console.log(store.name)` from app.js prints `undefined`

Any ideas why this doesnt work?

Comment: You should use store.getState() to get current value of store.

Comment: @udeepshrestha Thats right! Thank you! The tutorial i was watching didnt use .getState() but it worked either way. Not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`store.getState()`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) to access the current state.
`store.getState().name` should return the name. Since `store` doesn't have a `name` property, `undefined` is returned.

```
store.dispatch({ type: TEST })
console.log(store.getState().name)
```